# What is the difference between Array[n] ; and Array[ ]={ };

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, k, l;
    int temp;

    printf("Enter how many element on the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr1[100] = {};
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            if (arr1[j] > arr1[k]) {
                temp = arr1[j];
                arr1[j] = arr1[k];
                arr1[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d \t", arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

My code for sorting an array in ascending order works properly. And it doesn't have any error but when I am changed the array size then the code doesn't work properly and has an error called `stack smashing detected`. What causes this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, k, l;
    int temp;

    printf("Enter how many element on the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr1[] = {};
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            if (arr1[j] > arr1[k]) {
                temp = arr1[j];
                arr1[j] = arr1[k];
                arr1[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d \t", arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ultimately, `int arr1[]={};` ends up being the root of the impending *undefined behavior* doom that is about to transpire in the `scanf` code that follows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883363/the-difference-of-int-arr-and-int-arr-in-c

Comment: I am surprised gcc accepts `int a[] = {}` as valid code.  An array of  zero size initialized to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `int arr1[100] = {};` nor `int arr1[] = {};` is valid C code.

The program compiles because your compiler implements GNU extensions that allow empty initializers and zero length arrays.

The reason your program no longer works when you remove the length `100` is the array becomes too short for the elements you try and store into it.

You probably meant to write `int arr1[n] = {};` which does not compile because VLAs (variable sized arrays) cannot have an initializer.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, k, l;

    printf("Enter how many element on the array : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid size\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int arr1[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr1[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            if (arr1[j] > arr1[k]) {
                int temp = arr1[j];
                arr1[j] = arr1[k];
                arr1[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%c", arr1[i], "\t\n"[i == n - 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```